# Orbital resonance 2:1

Tags: orbit, asteroids, orbital-mechanics, celestial-mechanics, orbital-resonance

I considered the motion of an asteroid around the sun, in a $2:1$ orbital resonance with Jupiter. Following the study of this resonance, it was observed that the angle between the major axis of the asteroid's orbit and the Sun-Jupiter direction varies rapidly and decreases linearly over time.

I would like to ask you: how should I interpret the variation of this angle, in time?